# Can we specify when EmptyLineSeparator is apply according to class type in checkstyle?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I am using checkstyle for my java project with the file `google_checks.xml` (with modification to get an indent of 4 spaces).
When I scan I have `EmptyLineSeparator` for the `METHOD_DEF` token inside each Java interface.

Since my methods inside the interface don't have braces:

```
List<User> getAll ();
User findById (int userId);
// [...]
```

my linter removes the empty space between the lines, but checkstyle asks for them.

Is there a way to specify which file is affected by a checking rule, or is there a token for the interface method?

I know I can configure this in Intellij, but I am looking for a way for a team member to import the project and not have any additional configuration.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this is to suppress such violations by XPath using [SuppressionXpathFilter](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filters.html#SuppressionXpathFilter)

You need to create following file (or add entry to existing suppresion by xpath file). It will suppress violations from this check for all method definitions in interfaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionXpathFilter Experimental Configuration 1.2//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2_xpath_experimental.dtd">
<suppressions>
<suppress-xpath
       checks="EmptyLineSeparatorCheck"
       query="//INTERFACE_DEF/OBJBLOCK/METHOD_DEF"/>
</suppressions>
```

Your checkstyle config file should be extended with

```
<!-- should be under TreeWalker -->
<module name="SuppressionXpathFilter">
    <property name="file" value="/path/to/suppression-xpath.xml" />
    <property name="optional" value="false"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with [SuppressionFilter](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter). You can add a separate suppression file or just add it to your `google_checks.xml`. A good example can be found in Checkstyle's own suppression file at https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/config/suppressions.xml.

Your module should look something like this:

```
  <suppress checks="EmptyLineSeparator" files=".*YourFilenameHere\.java"/>
```

Comment: In this case, some other violations can be suppressed (for interface fields or if interface is nested). Plus, if there are a lot of files, regex can be long and difficult to maintain.

Comment: @strkk I agree, your answer should be accepted. I would upvote it, but I do not have enough reputation.